# After Submitting My App, iAds Have Stopped Working

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, itunes, iad

So I submitted my app last week and it was approved 2 days ago. I have iAd impleted in the app. As soon as the app was "ready for sale" I downloaded it from the App Store. When I launched the app everything worked. iAd was displaying ads on the screen. But then about 10 minutes later the ads stopped. It's been 2 days since the ads stopped and they still aren't showing up. I have even tried redownloading the app from the store several times. And it's not just me. It's happening to everyone who downloads the app. I'm sure I just need to contact Apple however it's the weekend and I just want to know as soon as possible, has anyone else had this problem? Or is it even a problem? I've read other questions asking similar things, however I believe mine may be different seeing as the ads displayed for the first 10 minutes. Also! When I go to iAds on iTunes Connect, it says "AD Status: live ads" and it's lit up green. Also in iAds it says "recieving live ads"

The app is free and if you'd like to see for yourself here is a link to the app: https://appsto.re/us/FB4u5.i

Other Information:

The app is an arcade game

Ages 4+

iAd works perfectly in the Xcode version of the app

I have tried the game on different wifi routers and on 4g to see if there was some connection issue

The ads that are meant to be displayed are banner ads at the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have an answer! I just contacted apple iAd support and its is very clear now as to why I haven't been seeing ads the past few days. Some people stated in the comments that even once your app has been approved and is ready for sale, the iAd has its own separate reviewing process, and this is exactly true. However, I revieved some extra information from the support team that should be able to clear things up without confusion for anyone having this problem in the future. First of all, while Apple may review apps on the weekend, the iAd team does not, my app was approved on Friday and this is why I haven't seen any ads all weekend. Second, even if your ad status in the iAd network is green and says "live: recieving live ads" this does not mean that iAd has reviewed your app yet, it simply means that you have done everything required on your end. Lastly, I was told that the separate iAd reviewing process usually takes two to three business days. I hope that this information will help others in the future not to be concerned if they are experiencing this behavior.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve your problem BCRwar1. I'm surprised Apple does not have someone from iAd there on the weekends to approve new apps. Good find.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem after updating my app. The ads were not displayed for about 2-3 days. After writing to Apple the problem was magically solved. I event did not get any answer from them.

I heard that Apple has an independent review process for iAds, maybe this could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried contacting Apple's iAd support about this? I've experienced similar problems in the past and contacting them cleared it up. I've read other solutions where issuing an update to the application fixed the problem also. iAd has to approve your app to receive ads even after your app has been accepted and made available for download. Perhaps they just over looked yours.

Comment: Yes I suppose that could be it. I guess ill find out tomorrow when I contact them and hopefully I will be able to post an answer to this question. I just think that it's weird how it says on the iAd site that my ad status is "receiving live ads"

Comment: @BCRwar1 Yeah it can be quite frustrating trying to figure this problem out. My ad status was also "Receiving Live Ads" when I experienced my similar problem. Hopefully iAd's support team is able to solve it for you.